# Express "tornado" and "hurricane" in Russian

Tags: перевод, словоупотребление, значения

What's the best way to express **tornado** and **hurricane** in Russian? From Wiktionary and Google Images, it looks like **ураган** can mean both, so how should one express each separately?

For example: *"Are you more scared of tornadoes or hurricanes?"*

Comment: Example makes almost no sence if translated literally. One have to know a lot about weather and atmoshpere to know a difference. And if he does know that much, why should he be scared? "What do you think is more dangerous?.."  question is more suitable in this case.
OK, after googling this I do know that смерч does not always come with ураган, and otherwise. But before that I thought that we will be able to locate воронку смерча if met ураган.

Comment: Торнадо has already come into Russian, though смерч is also in use. Ураган is used more often.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that tornado is "смерч" and hurricane is "ураган".
In my understanding tornado are very rare in Russia, that's why "смерч" word is also pretty rare, so not even every people could say the difference from "ураган"
And the "ураган" phonetically pretty similar to hurricane, so it is pretty much the same word and notion.

Ураган is often used as a synonym to "strong wind", not the actual hurricane.

Answer (score 13):

I think **ураган** can mean both, but rarely, because to refer to a tornado, we have two words in Russian:

- *торнадо* - is a tornado in North America.
- *смерч* - this word is used, if we are talking about a "tornado" elsewhere, they are much less powerful. We usually do not use торнадо to refer to a whirlwind for instance in Russia.

*ураган* - is usually about a hurricane, I mean a wind, weather conditions on much larger area compared to a tornado, and we do not use it widely (if at all) to refer to a tornado or a whirlwind.

Answer (score 3):

I believe tornado is `смерч` in Russian.

```
Чего больше боишься - урагана или смерчей?
```

Comment: я реально не понимаю, за что тут уже два плюса этому ответу. Он же просто вводит человека в заблуждение. "a tornado" по-русски - смерч **ИЛИ** торнадо. Мы не говорим никогда, что "в Техасе был смерч". За что плюсы?

Comment: На окраине Хановера (штат Индиана) Сильвия Хъюмс увидела «три воронки» в пятнадцати футах над землей. «Они ревели, как огромная кофемолка. Самый большой смерч разнес в щепки автоприцеп неподалеку. ...
«Мезенцев В. А. Энциклопедия чудес. Кн. I. Обычное в необычном»: Знание; М.; 1988

Comment: @НадеждаТарашкевич, указывайте ник через собаку, чтоб тот, к кому адресовано, мог получить уведомление

Comment: @НадеждаТарашкевич, хорошо, я перефразирую с тем, что "никогда не говори никогда". Да, может где-то в какой-то книжке кто-то так и перевел. Но навряд ли вы будете отрицать, что сегодня в СМИ и вообще в обиходе, мы именуем торнадо в США именно как "торнадо", а не "смерч"?

Comment: @user907860 в Техасе - торнадо, но мы его не боимся (он в Техасе, а мы в Рязани). А в Рязани мы боимся смерча (но не очень, они раз в десятилетие бывают)

Если это перевод, можно и "торнадо"

Comment: @user907860, да это из-за медиа. Им накладно переводчиков толковых нанять. Торнадо - это и есть смерч. А вот американская рулетка уже всюду называется - русская. Если бы в голливудских фильмах больше снимали про американские горки - то они бы тоже сейчас назывались русскими. Как правило под торнадо подразумевается разрушительный смерч, у нас таких не бывает почти - а вот пакеты и мусор всякий уносит, пыль гоняет.

Comment: @IvanBlack, из-за таких вот понятий о "толковых переводчиках", о "правильном", как ваши, и появляются мертвые языки. 50 лет назад, возможно, слово "торнадо" не было слишком в ходу, поэтому в переводах использовали "смерч". Но сегодня оно в ходу, и "правильным", по моему мнению, в языке есть то, что широко распространено и не звучит беспричинно странно. Может по-вашему "топор" тоже неправильно использовать? Ведь "по-правильному"-то, "секира" должно быть, да?

Comment: @user907860, честно говоря ваше описание причин появления мёртвых языков мне кажется сомнительным. Ровно как и то, что слово торнадо - "в ходу". Суда же и тот факт, что секиру с топором путают только дети. Если бы вы, господин, черпали знания из литературы, а не из низкосортного зарубежного кинематографа, то, вероятно, слово смерч, вам не казалось бы таким уж редким в сравнении с торнадо. И я не увидел ни одной причины, нивелирующей проблему перевода.

Comment: @IvanBlack, про мертвые языки. Смотрите, у вас есть живой язык, на котором говорят люди и который всем понятен и звучит естественно. Потом появляются такие как вы и начинают рассказывать про "высокую литературу", "правильность" и т.п. В результате, через несколько сотен лет "ученый" класс использует язык, который хрен кто вообще понимает, что наносит колоссальный вред науке без кавычек и прогрессу. Потому что человеку для получения, описания и передачи какой-то важной практической информации, например, в математике, надо помимо математики еще и этот язык освоить. Надеюсь, так яснее?

Comment: слово смерч, вам не казалось бы таким уж редким в сравнении с торнадо. Да мне оно не кажется, я просто говорю о том, что сегодня в живом языке, который в ходу, которым все пользуются, говорят так, и надо об этом сообщать тому, кто изучает язык, а не рассказывать про *надо говорить "смерч", чтоб сойти за литературоведа*. А вообще, есть только один критерий "правильности" в вопросах языка - степень общепринятости

Comment: @user907860 я по-прежнему не понимаю, чем вам смерч не угодил.

Comment: тем, что это слово относительно, редко, даже очень, используется по отношению к Сев. Америке в современном, живом русском языке. Сравните кол-во результатов в гугле: [457 тыс.](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=смерч+в+сша) и [15,9 млн.](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=торнадо+в+сша). При такой разнице для многих людей "смерч" по отношению к Сев. Америке покажется странным и неестественным.

Comment: да и то, в запросе "смерч в США" большая часть результатов, по крайней мере на первой странице, именно о торнадо !

Comment: @user907860 а где шла речь о Северной Америке? В посте такого нет, ни явно, ни из контекста.

Comment: у вас, вообще, с логикой в порядке все? В посте шла речь о "a hurricane" и "tornado" вообще, не в Сев. Америке, не в Евразии, а в мире, в Солнечной системе, во Вселенной и параллельных мирах. Поэтому Сев. Америка в данные множества как бы включена, да? И т.к. по отношению к ней слово "смерч" практически не применяется, то это важный момент, о котором надо указать в ответе

Comment: @user907860 не кипятитесь. Контекст таков, что ответы про русский язык непременно должны быть действительны в России и окрестностях. Остальное - на усмотрение. Иначе перейдём к "вам послайсить или одним писом".